# Jquery backdrop modal popup

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am looking for jQuery modal popup which should display image like sample check to show routing number etc,.. When I click on a Routing number(?)question mark it should pop-up an image and should have closing button on the top right corner. I have seen different approaches but couldnt find exact one

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [Bootstrap Modal](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals).  Click the `Launch demo modal` button.

In `<head>` make sure you include the javascript for `jquery` and `bootstrap.js`.  You can download `bootstrap.js` from the bootstrap site.  You also might want to include the `bootstrap.css` as well.

Once your `<head>` is all setup, in your body you need to add the modal code which will be hidden and you'll need to add a button to show the modal.  The button and modal are linked together by `id`.

```
<!-- Button to trigger modal -->
<a href="#myModal" role="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal">Launch demo modal</a>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
    <h3 id="myModalLabel">Modal header</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p>One fine body…</p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you please show me how to put the code and make it runnable. I looking for the perfect example you showed to me.